Using GEMINI through proxy
I try to run this code
import google.generativeai as genai
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'socks5://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'socks5://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'socks5://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'socks5://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'
genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"])

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash")
response = model.generate_content(["Hi"])
print(response.text)

but i got an error FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use. in Jupyter cell output
I guess that it connected with another error with proxy. I got in terminal E0000 00:00:1729659835.353406   15272 http_proxy_mapper.cc:135] 'socks5' scheme not supported in proxy URI
Also this code worked well some days ago
How can I fix this error
full traceback
FailedPrecondition                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 x = model.generate_content(["Hi"])

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\generativeai\generative_models.py:331, in GenerativeModel.generate_content(self, contents, generation_config, safety_settings, stream, tools, tool_config, request_options)
    329         return generation_types.GenerateContentResponse.from_iterator(iterator)
    330     else:
--> 331         response = self._client.generate_content(
    332             request,
    333             **request_options,
    334         )
    335         return generation_types.GenerateContentResponse.from_response(response)
    336 except google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument as e:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\ai\generativelanguage_v1beta\services\generative_service\client.py:830, in GenerativeServiceClient.generate_content(self, request, model, contents, retry, timeout, metadata)
    827 self._validate_universe_domain()
    829 # Send the request.
--> 830 response = rpc(
    831     request,
    832     retry=retry,
    833     timeout=timeout,
    834     metadata=metadata,
    835 )
    837 # Done; return the response.
    838 return response

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py:131, in _GapicCallable.__call__(self, timeout, retry, compression, *args, **kwargs)
    128 if self._compression is not None:
    129     kwargs["compression"] = compression
--> 131 return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\retry\retry_unary.py:293, in Retry.__call__.<locals>.retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    289 target = functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    290 sleep_generator = exponential_sleep_generator(
    291     self._initial, self._maximum, multiplier=self._multiplier
    292 )
--> 293 return retry_target(
    294     target,
    295     self._predicate,
    296     sleep_generator,
    297     timeout=self._timeout,
    298     on_error=on_error,
    299 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\retry\retry_unary.py:153, in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, timeout, on_error, exception_factory, **kwargs)
    149 # pylint: disable=broad-except
    150 # This function explicitly must deal with broad exceptions.
    151 except Exception as exc:
    152     # defer to shared logic for handling errors
--> 153     _retry_error_helper(
    154         exc,
    155         deadline,
    156         sleep,
    157         error_list,
    158         predicate,
    159         on_error,
    160         exception_factory,
    161         timeout,
    162     )
    163     # if exception not raised, sleep before next attempt
    164     time.sleep(sleep)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\retry\retry_base.py:212, in _retry_error_helper(exc, deadline, next_sleep, error_list, predicate_fn, on_error_fn, exc_factory_fn, original_timeout)
    206 if not predicate_fn(exc):
    207     final_exc, source_exc = exc_factory_fn(
    208         error_list,
    209         RetryFailureReason.NON_RETRYABLE_ERROR,
    210         original_timeout,
    211     )
--> 212     raise final_exc from source_exc
    213 if on_error_fn is not None:
    214     on_error_fn(exc)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\retry\retry_unary.py:144, in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, timeout, on_error, exception_factory, **kwargs)
    142 for sleep in sleep_generator:
    143     try:
--> 144         result = target()
    145         if inspect.isawaitable(result):
    146             warnings.warn(_ASYNC_RETRY_WARNING)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py:120, in TimeToDeadlineTimeout.__call__.<locals>.func_with_timeout(*args, **kwargs)
    117     # Avoid setting negative timeout
    118     kwargs["timeout"] = max(0, self._timeout - time_since_first_attempt)
--> 120 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py:78, in _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     76     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     77 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 78     raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc

FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use.



FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use.

Means that you request is sending from a country where its not supported  make sure its running in one of the available-regions

I sure that error  FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use is a consequence of problem with proxy server. And the main question of this post is how to fix error with proxy 'socks5' scheme not supported in proxy URI

As you wish but thats what the error means.    I will delete this if you like.

Use ControlD instead of a proxy. In the application, in the configuration field, write "comss" and run it. Works unlimited and stable. Good luck)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
